# Div on top of slider

Tags: css, positioning, html

Hello I have a slider in my webpage and I want to place a small box on the top of that slider. How can i achieve this with css positioning?

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="captionBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="captionBox"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {position:relative}
#captionBox {position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
```

You can change top and left to px values also e.g 10px. You can also then apply z-index css rules for layering effects

explanation

An absolute positioned element is positioned at an offset to the boundary of its nearest ascendant that has relative positioning. An absolute positioned element is ignored in the flow of an HTML document so you cannot float it